# Can Only Sequential Experiments Have Non-Independent Events?

Tags: probability

Fellow Mathers,

Can only Sequential Experiments have Non-Independent Events?

**Definitions of What I Mean:**

> Two Events are Independent if P(A⋂B)=P(A)P(B)
>
> An Experiment is Sequential if it has a multi-element event in its Event Space.
>
> [i.e. S = {... , {A,B, .... }, ...}]

I am asking this as all the examples of Non-Independent Events I can muster up are events that have a sequence of outcome stages to the experiment (e.g. playing two rounds of Russian Roulette), but I have no idea where to take it from here in terms of formally proving/disproving the idea.

Thanks to any who can provide insight. Much thanks to any who can provide an insightful proof/disproof. -SDH

Comment: Ahhh your definition is wrong

Comment: And one event cant be independent, it's a relative term

Comment: Yup, that was just stupidity lol. Intersection, not Union.

Comment: Can you explain that last comment, the relative term

Comment: "An Event is Independent if P(A ⋂ B) = P(A)P(B)" That is sloppily stated. You should say instead that _two_ events A,B are indepedent if P(A ⋂ B) = P(A)P(B). $\qquad$

Comment: The sample space consisting (*or not consisting*) of "sequential" outcomes has no influence on whether or not there exist (*or don't exist*) independent (*or dependent*) pairs of events.  As for an example of an experiment with non-trivial dependent events... consider a deck of cards and drawing one card from the deck.  Compare the events "You drew a spade" which occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ versus "You drew a black card" which occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.  Their intersection occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}\neq \frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}$ so they are dependent.

Comment: Your question seems to be focused on whether or not a pair of dependent events exists specifically... It is easy to see that any probability space with more than one non-null outcome in the sample space has examples of dependent events.  Let $A$ be an event such that $0<Pr(A)<1$.  Then $A^c$ is also an event such that $0<Pr(A^c)<1$ and is dependent on $A$ since $0<Pr(A)\cdot Pr(A^c)\neq Pr(A\cap A^c)=0$

Comment: @JMoravitz Hello! You mind writing that as an answer? I'll close the question with that as a Disproof.